# rGoogleAnalytics ValidateToken() working in RStudio but not R

Tags: r, google-analytics, rstudio, google-analytics-api

I am using rGoogleAnalytics in RStudio and it is working fine. My code simply loads an authorised token and validates it.

```
require(RGoogleAnalytics)
load("......./token_file")
ValidateToken(token)
```

When I run this in RStudio (Version 1.0.136) I get the message:

> Access Token successfully updated

But when I run in R (3.3.3) I get the message:

> Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection
>
> Calls: ValidateToken ...  ->  -> cache_token -> saveRDS -> gzfile
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In gzfile(file, mode) :
>
> cannot open compressed file '.httr-oauth', probable reason 'Permission denied'
>
> Execution halted

I am trying to run the code as a batch process which is why I am using R and not RStudio.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm stuck on similar